# How to open application with notification from LocalNotifications plugin in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I'm developing a PhoneGap/Cordova application, I've succesfully added LocalNotifications using this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification; however, I've one little issue, when I tap the notification in the Notifications window my application isn't opened, I mean, nothing happens, could someone explain me how to open it when someone tap on a notification from my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, in AlarmReceiver.class take a look to the line with:

PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);

Replace with:

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourApp.class); final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Where YourApp.class is the class that you want to open